# JMESPath how to query by dynamic key?

Tags: jmespath

How to get "beta" from following structure?

```
{ 
  "key": "b", 
  "data":{
    "a": "alpha", 
    "b": "beta"
  }
}
```

Comment: If the structure is assigned to a variable, e.g. "instance", then as follows …
    instance["data"]["b"]

Comment: the value "b" is not deterministic, it's from "key".